# Why Bloc not in the context?

Tags: flutter, bloc

I have BlocProvider widget above the widget where I'm trying to dispatch event, but I still getting `BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a Bloc of type RenderBloc.`

This is what my build method returns:

```
return BlocProvider<RenderBloc>(
  builder: (BuildContext context) => RenderBloc(),  
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      FlatButton(
        child: Text('Render'),
        onPressed: () {
          BlocProvider.of<RenderBloc>(context).add(RenderProjectEvent(project));
        },
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

I also tried with `MultiBlocProvider`, got the same.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create another inner context (using *Builder*, for example) to access *InheritedWidget* (Provider):

```dart
return BlocProvider<RenderBloc>(
  builder: (BuildContext context) => RenderBloc(),  
  child: Builder(
    builder: (cxt) {
      return Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Render'),
            onPressed: () {
              BlocProvider.of<RenderBloc>(cxt).add(RenderProjectEvent(project));
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  }
);
```